# Price per 100 pieces?

Tags: word-choice, business-language

In business English, what is the correct way to say:

> Price per 100 pieces?

the context is a table listing unit price when the overall quantity is of 100 pieces.

In short: if you buy 100 pieces, the price for every single piece is: [price here]

Comment: "Price per 100 pieces" is fine, although *pieces* might be unusual; *items* or actually naming the objects might be more usual. It also implies that the item can **only** be ordered in multiples of 100.

Comment: I would interpret _price per 100 pieces_ as meaning the total price you pay for 100 items of whatever item you’re talking about. _Unit price_ or _price per unit_ is the normal term for the price of a single unit. _Unit price when purchasing 100 items_ or something similar to that would be unambiguous.

Comment: thank you all. how can I write it in short? it's a table.

Comment: what do you think of: "Unit price (20 Pieces)"

Comment: I agree with @JanusBahsJacquet.  I would interpret it the same way.  Please see my descriptive answer below.  Hope it helps.

Comment: @Jess “Unit price (20 items)” works fine for a table header. It is perhaps not entirely unambiguous, but at least unlikely to be misinterpreted. I would still, as Andrew said, avoid using _pieces_—that sounds quite odd, unless there is something specific in the context that makes it clear that they are actual pieces (if the things you’re selling are all chess pieces, for example). _Units_ or _items_ are both far more natural-sounding.

Comment: British and American English does **not** use "piece" in the same way that it is used on the Indian subcontinent. "How much is a piece?" is not idiomatic unless you are taking about a slice of something.

Answer (score 7):

Let us say one piece costs $10.  So 10 pieces would cost $100.  Say, if someone buys 100 or more pieces, you provide a 10% discount.  In this case, 100 pieces would cost $900, 110 pieces would cost $990, and so the unit price would be $9.

Now, let's summarize the usage:

If you want to refer to the **total cost for all 100 pieces sold as a single unit**, use:

> Price per 100 pieces

If you want to refer to the **price of each piece**, use:

> Price per piece (or unit price)

If it is **price of each piece when someone buys at least 100 pieces**, use:

> Unit price for a minimum purchase of 100 pieces

I think it is the last one you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much. anyway i need a short form: what do you think of "Unit price for 100 pieces" ?

Comment: That could be taken to mean 100 pieces as a single unit, @JessStone.  I can't think of something really crisp, but something like "Unit price (100-unit minimum)" when listed right next to "Unit price (no minimum)" would certainly make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

We call that "quantity pricing".  So the price if you buy 100 is the **Quantity 100 Price**.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of this one?

[image]

It's quite short and clear, without having to use a word/phrase to explain it.

[This](http://www.officedepot.com/a/products/812724/12-Breakaway-Lanyard-With-Key-Ring/) website is using that pricing system, and I think it's understandable enough. (:

Maybe just to make it even clearer, change the title of the second column to "Price/Item" or "Price per Item".